# Powershell: Unable to parse json returned from Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: json, powershell

I try to parse a json string returned from an API call.

```
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URIValue -Method Post -Headers $Headers -Body $requestBody -ContentType 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

$Response #Returns: {"results":[{"tables":[{"rows":[{"[Quantity]":200}]}]}]}
```

Now that I try to parse it `Response | ConvertFrom-Json` I get the following error: `ConvertFrom-Json: Conversion from JSON failed with error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Invoke-Restmethod already returns a deserialized json or xml object

Comment: For some reason it is returning a string?

Comment: maybe the server returns some invalid json? try dumping `$Response` to a file and double check that for any invalid characters like `Out-File -Path 'C:\tmp\response.txt' -InputObject $Response`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual solution:

$Response.Substring(1) | ConvertFrom-Json